# How to output words above text in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, part-of-speech

I have a **structure** with two members: `word`:string and `pos`:int (part of speech).

And I want to output `words` with their `pos` above in `QTextEdit` like this

[image]

Is this even possible or it's easier to make colorful font and background with `SyntaxHighlighter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the text as html:

```
QString pos = "Hello. p .v.";
QString word = "word";

ui->textEdit->setHtml("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">"
                     "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">"
                     "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }"
                     "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:'Ubuntu'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">"
                     "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-style:italic; color:#888a85;\">" + pos + ". </span></p>"
                     "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#2e3436;\">" + word + "</span></p></body></html>");
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there appers another problem... No way I can output an array with loop using html (array length may change)

Comment: then worte your custom textEdit